# stop company-complete-selection from eating following word in rust code?

Tags: rust, emacs, rust-analyzer, company-mode

Say I have a piece of code like `foo.bar()`, but I realize I need to change it to `foo.unwrap().bar()`. If I first move to the position after the dot, and start typing `unwrap`, I'll reach a state like `foo.unw^bar()` (where `^` denotes my cursor position). At this point, if I use `company-complete-selection` to complete `unwrap`, it turns into `foo.unwrap()`, i.e. the `bar` gets eaten.

Note that this "eating" gets blocked by punctuation, e.g. If I have `foo..bar()`, and position myself between the two dots, type `unw` and then complete, I get `foo.unwrap^.bar()`, which is what I want (`^` is again cursor position).

I'm using doom emacs, writing rust code with lsp-mode and rustic-mode (and company-mode). I actually don't know if this is an issue with company, or if it's rust-specific. Maybe the rust language server (rust-analyzer) is providing company with "completions" that include eating the following word?

I haven't tested whether this type of issue applies

- in non-rust buffers
- in other editors using LSP with rust-analyzer

Comment: I can verify that rust-analyzer on VS Code does _not_ do this. You get `foo.unwrap^bar()` and have to put the parens in yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `lsp-completion-default-behaviour` controls this.  You can change it to `:insert` instead of `:replace` to get that behaviour.